# Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for get()

Tags: angular, jasmine

Please help me resolve the following error:

Error:  : could not find an object to spy upon for get()
Usage: spyOn(, )

Offending code:

```
describe('blah blah blah', () => {

  let apiService: ApiService;
    fit('click confirm delete should delete the asset', fakeAsync(() => {
      
      apiService = TestBed.inject(ApiService) as jasmine.SpyObj<ApiService>;
      spyOn(apiService, 'get').and.returnValue(of({entity: ASSET} as unknown as HttpResponse<null>));

      component.reload();
      fixture.detectChanges();

...
      expect(component.asset).toBeFalsy();
      expect(apiService.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
});
```